# How to automatically copy to a specific physical usb port

Tags: python, file, copy

Hi so I am wondering if there is a way to copy files to any usb connected without a idv nor idp,
Also I am wondering if there is a way to assign the above only to a specific usb port so that other ports cold be used without files automatically copied over?
I have not tried much a am still in the process of self learning
Any help would be highly appreciated.
p.s a am using windows

Comment: Please checkout out the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that will explain you how to write good questions, and get answers from other users (and give help to others as well). Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use the `os` library where you can specify your location in the first argument.

```py
import os
os.path.join(dir_path, 'filename.txt')
```

or you can just use `open` and use `D:` or whatever the drive letter is. This can be very useful especially if you set your usb drive to a specific letter. If you want to make your drive a specific letter there are many tutorials for that online.

```py
var = open('D:/path/to/dir/filename.txt', 'w')
```

Comment: Thank you, First do you mined explaining your first option please, second I need this to work with multipole drives so that the second option would not work. Thank you again.